# Features to generate time expiring

Tags: licensing

There are something out of box to generate time expiring in php? 
For example I need to control the access to the system, I was thinking something to verify every first day of every month, and do this in my code.

But it is not 100% safety, since another programmer can remove this line code that verify. Then I thought is it possible, to verify in another server, if the monthly time expire or not? and return the message to the user if the copy expired or not?

What is the best to way to create a licensing features for time expiry?
or I really need to get inside IonCube (Compiled Code Encoding) for example?

What is the best practice?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague without a clear explanation of what of your code runs on a server, what on the client, who has access to the code etc.

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/214158/ In short: think about the business model, not the locking technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What first comes to mind is a web validation, each time the users logs in. So , when you make the package, your first write a line with a request to a page of yours with a license-number and that way check consistency. Also, from your site, you should check that if a license has not registered any activity in, lets say a month, then ask for explanations to the people who bought it.

Hope this helps, it aint bullet proof but cuold work!

EDIT:

After the commend and reading some internet articles i found some nice php obfuscators OpenSource. Read [this article](http://www.seocompany.ca/software/free-encryption-software.html) and see for yourself. This will avoid removing the line of code.

Comment: and If someone remove the line from my file.php for example, verification will fail. I'm really confused about what is the best way, I have already a program I did myself, it control the application by month, it is a verification program that need to control de access to the application. The problem is how can I hidden the verification on application's side? The program to verify will reside in another webserver (not the same of my application). Am I clear? thanks.